# How to insert rows in DataTable using JSON data from Flask

Tags: python, jquery, json, flask, datatables

I'm processing the data in Python/Flask, sending to the page using `return jsonify`, in console the data is shown, but nothing is inserted to the datatables.

Backend

```
table_rows = []
table_rows.append([''.join(['<img src="https://easyvs.unifei.edu.br/static/mol_img/hit_', str(result_of_docking[1]), '.png" alt="', str(result_of_docking[4]), '" height=100 width=100 onerror="this.src=', "'", '../static/images/mol_not_ready.png', "'", '></img>']), str(result_of_docking[4]), str(round(result_of_docking[2], 2)), str(round(result_of_docking[5], 2)) ])
return jsonify(table_rows=table_rows)
```

Frontend:

```
var t = $("#tb_docking_data").DataTable();
t.rows.add(data.table_rows).draw();
```

Comment: Can you share a sample of the data you try to insert into DataTables? Chances are if it's not structured properly you fail to do that.

Comment: Also need to show how you receive that data in front end